# Failed to start the resumable upload (HTTP 404)

Tags: php, youtube, google-client-login

Here is my code, I am trying for a couple of hours to fix this problem, the only error that I am getting is: **Failed to start the resumable upload (HTTP 404)**

Is there a way to see more error details, or do you guys know what may cause this error? I have granted access and everything, I check for expired tokens as well, but can't upload a video b/c of this.

Please at least a hint about how can I see more error details.
......

```
    //Check if token is valid
    if($this->client->isAccessTokenExpired()){
        //var_dump($this->client->getAccessToken());
        $NewAccessToken = json_decode($this->client->getAccessToken());
        $d = $this->client->refreshToken($NewAccessToken->refresh_token);

        $this->client->setAccessToken(trim($this->client->getAccessToken()));
    }
```

.........

```
                try{
                    // REPLACE this value with the path to the file you are uploading.
                    $videoPath = $_FILES['video']['tmp_name'];

                    // Create a snippet with title, description, tags and category ID
                    // Create an asset resource and set its snippet metadata and type.
                    // This example sets the video's title, description, keyword tags, and
                    // video category.
                    $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
                    $snippet->setTitle($_POST['title']);
                    $snippet->setDescription($this->input->post('description'));
                    $snippet->setTags(array("tag1", "tag2"));

                    // Numeric video category. See
                    // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
                    $snippet->setCategoryId("22");

                    // Set the video's status to "public". Valid statuses are "public",
                    // "private" and "unlisted".
                    $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
                    $status->privacyStatus = "unlisted";

                    // Associate the snippet and status objects with a new video resource.
                    $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
                    $video->setSnippet($snippet);
                    $video->setStatus($status);

                    // Specify the size of each chunk of data, in bytes. Set a higher value for
                    // reliable connection as fewer chunks lead to faster uploads. Set a lower
                    // value for better recovery on less reliable connections.
                    $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

                    // Setting the defer flag to true tells the client to return a request which can be called
                    // with ->execute(); instead of making the API call immediately.
                    $this->client->setDefer(true);

                    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
                    $ext= finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['video']['tmp_name']);

                    // Create a request for the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
                    $insertRequest = $this->youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video,
                                     array("data"=>file_get_contents($_FILES['video']['tmp_name']),
                                           "uploadType" => "media",
                                           "mimeType" => 'application/octet-stream'));

                    // Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads.
                    $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
                        $this->client,
                        $insertRequest,
                        'video/*',
                        null,
                        true,
                        $chunkSizeBytes
                    );
                    $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));


                    // Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
                    $status = false;
                    $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
                    while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
                        $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
                        $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
                    }

                    fclose($handle);

                    // If you want to make other calls after the file upload, set setDefer back to false
                    $this->client->setDefer(false);
                    $videoID = $status['id'];

                } catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
                        $response['success'] = 'Failed to upload video, contact support! a Message:'.$e->getMessage();
                        return $this->output
                        ->set_content_type('application/json')
                        ->set_output(json_encode($response));
                } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
                        $response['success'] = 'Failed to upload video, contact support! b Message:'.$e->getMessage();
                        return $this->output
                        ->set_content_type('application/json')
                        ->set_output(json_encode($response));
                }
```

//LE

```
 ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Exception' with message 'Failed to start the resumable upload (HTTP 404)' in /home/user/app/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/MediaFileUpload.php on line 299
( ! ) Google_Exception: Failed to start the resumable upload (HTTP 404) in /home/user/app/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/MediaFileUpload.php on line 299
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  285400  {main}( )   .../index.php:0
2   0.0162  1112448 require_once( '/home/user/app/system/core/CodeIgniter.php' )    .../index.php:210
3   0.0633  4532576 call_user_func_array:{/home/mio/zsuite-dev/system/core/CodeIgniter.php:359} ( ) .../CodeIgniter.php:359
4   0.0634  4534256 Presentation->index( )  .../CodeIgniter.php:359
5   0.4291  8672016 Presentation->_save_update_presentation( )  .../presentation.php:155
6   0.4952  9206376 Google_Http_MediaFileUpload->nextChunk( )   .../presentation.php:289
7   0.4952  9206736 Google_Http_MediaFileUpload->getResumeUri( )    .../MediaFileUpload.php:138
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check your `php` error logs.

- In Linux environment it should be at: `var/log/httpd/error_log`
- In Windows environment you should check your `php.ini`

`error_log = c:/server/php.log` line to find the location.

EDIT: if you don't have errors enabled, change the following line in your `php.ini`

`log_errors = On`

and reproduce the error.

EDIT2: the following [page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php) also seems to have a lot of samples if you haven't already looked at it.

Answer (score 0):

ClientLogin for Google has been shutdown: [see here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthForInstalledApps)

I recently had to re-code authentication on an app to fix the issue. You must now use OAuth to authenticate with Google. The good news: there is plenty of code out there to help you including on Google: [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2)